# Parsing and dynamically allocating substrings with inconsistant sizes using sscanf

Tags: c

I implemented a read_line function:

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>


char* read_line(){
    const char UNIX_LINEBREAK = '\n';
    const char WINDOWS_LINEBREAK = '\r';
    const char C_STRING_TERMINATOR = '\0';
    
    char extra_linebreak;
    char current_letter;

    char* line = NULL;
    int position = 0;
    bool reading_line = true;
    

    while(reading_line){
        scanf("%c", &current_letter);
        if(current_letter == UNIX_LINEBREAK || current_letter == EOF){
            reading_line = false;
        }
        else if(current_letter == WINDOWS_LINEBREAK) {
            reading_line = false;
            extra_linebreak = (char)getchar();
        }
        else {
            line = (char*) realloc(line, sizeof(char) * (position +  1));
            line[position] = current_letter;
            position ++;
        }
    }

    line = (char*) realloc(line, sizeof(char) * (position +  1));
    line[position] = C_STRING_TERMINATOR;

    return line; 
}
```

Which I'm using for reading strings in the format:

```
operation number number
```

for example:

```
sum 13 13
```

However I'm implementing operations with numbers that may (and will) overflow the max int size. For example:

```
sum 23879238932898239832983298329839229383928329 239823983298392893289238932883290312803291832109230189
```

Which forces me to read them in a string format, parse them and finally work with them through a linked list (There may be better approaches but that's not the point yet). By now, I'm trying to use auxiliary buffers (`operation`,  `first_number_buffer` and `second_number_buffer`) with `sscanf` for splitting the line read with `read_line` in three substrings.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline.h>

int main (){
    char* line = read_line();
    char operation[4];
    char* first_number_buffer;
    char* second_number_buffer;

    sscanf(line, "%s %s %s", operation, first_number_buffer, second_number_buffer);

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", line,first_number_buffer,second_number_buffer);

}
```

The code above doesn't work very well, since I'm not really allocating `first_number_buffer` and `second_number_buffer` yet. I would like to know if there's an efficient way for using sscanf in that situation. I didn't manage to find good results in google, since scanf overlaps sscanf results.

The problem seems to be: Usually, to dynamically allocate a string, one uses `realloc` to grow it size one by one. However sscanf tries to "throw" all the content of the parsed substring at once. Since strings have inconsistent sizes I cannot simply make them static, like I did with `operation`.

Yes, I could use a big static buffer but that seems to be an important task, and since I'm an undergrad I would like to know the proper way to to that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `scanf("%c", &current_letter);` -> `current_letter = getchar();` Change type for `current_letter` to `int`.

Comment: Your thought for using a linked-list for processing the "big numbers" is fine. There are examples on this site of just that. You may want to reallocate in blocks of 1024 and keep track of space `avaialble` and `used` and only reallocate when `available == used`. `realloc()` for every character is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks David! That's a generic read_line() function I've made sometime ago. The issue is not on that function, there's surely way for improving (for example, I yet didn't divide it in smaller functions) but it works! I've tested it for all the inputs I have to read, the issue is definitely on allocating the buffers

Comment: You've not allocated space for `first_number_buffer` or `second_number_buffer`, so everything goes haywire when you execute `sscanf(line, "%s %s %s", operation, first_number_buffer, second_number_buffer);`.  If you've got a sufficiently POSIX-compatible operating system (runtime C library), you can use `%ms` for the two numbers and pass `&first_number_buffer` and `&second_number_buffer`.  Otherwise, you have to impose a limit on the length of the numbers (1024 perhaps?) and work from there.

Comment: Yes, I know that's not your problem, that's why I noted with a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure on how /when to allocate space for them. I could do an initial malloc for the pointers when declaring them, but I don't think that changes much. They would have a small size and sscanf would try to fit a big (unkown) amount of memory when it runs! That's the point were I didn't know what to do

Comment: Parsing input with `scanf`-like functions works well until it doesn't. This feels like the type of input where you might want to use a tokenizer to cut up your input (even `strtok` is fine), and then a parser that handles the grammar.

Comment: I didn't knew `strtok` existed. Thank you very much @Cheatah! It seems to return a pointer to the first occurrence of a token in a string. I may be able to use it to allocate space to my numbers beyond that point. I'll try it, it seems like a solution!!!!!

Comment: Well, the number strings are already allocated in your line buffer. So really you might just only need to keep track of a few pointers where the numbers start.

Comment: You need to test the return value from `scanf()` in general.  In particular, your code `scanf("%c", &current_letter); if(current_letter == UNIX_LINEBREAK || current_letter == EOF){ reading_line = false; }` will not detect EOF.  You should use `while (scanf("%c", &current_letter) == 1 && current_letter != UNIX_LINEBREAK) { … }`.

Comment: Your `read_line()` function appears to allocate space for the whole line.  You can then either carve it into subsections (someone else mentioned `strtok()`, which will do the job but isn't as good a choice as `strtok_r()` (POSIX) or `strtok_s()` (Windows). if either of those is available), or calculate the field lengths and allocate the appropriate amount of space for the fields.  Note that you should not use `%s`; you should use `%3s` (for example) with `char operation[4];` to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: Uuuuh, I see! I tried to store EOF in a variable but failed, since it's not an ASCII character. Then proceeded to do what I did, but after reading your explanation it's clear why it won't work. Thanks @JonathanLeffler I'll refactor it!

Comment: That read_line() is a generic function I made some time ago, that I re-use it in a lot of projects, it's meant to read a line until \n or \r\n and return that line, it was not designed/optimized for the operations with big numbers task. But i'll definetely use the %3s tip, thanks @JonathanLeffler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I manage to do what I initially intended.

It's hard to use `sscanf` for the task, since one would have to previously allocate the memory necessary for `sscanf` to use. Which, in the context of the question, is unknown.

However, @Cheatah suggested using `strtok`, which worked pretty fine. Here's the final version of the code, using it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>



char* read_line(){
    const char UNIX_LINEBREAK = '\n';
    const char WINDOWS_LINEBREAK = '\r';
    const char C_STRING_TERMINATOR = '\0';
    
    char extra_linebreak;
    char current_letter;

    char* line = NULL;
    int position = 0;
    bool reading_line = true;
    

    while(reading_line){
        scanf("%c", &current_letter);
        if(current_letter == UNIX_LINEBREAK || current_letter == EOF){
            reading_line = false;
        }
        else if(current_letter == WINDOWS_LINEBREAK) {
            reading_line = false;
            extra_linebreak = (char)getchar();
        }
        else {
            line = (char*) realloc(line, sizeof(char) * (position +  1));
            line[position] = current_letter;
            position ++;
        }
    }

    line = (char*) realloc(line, sizeof(char) * (position +  1));
    line[position] = C_STRING_TERMINATOR;

    return line; 
}

int main (){
    char* line = read_line();
    char* operation;
    char* first_number_buffer;
    char* second_number_buffer;

    char *line_split = strtok(line,  " ");
    operation = (char *) malloc(strlen(line_split) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(operation, line_split);

    line_split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    first_number_buffer = (char *) malloc(strlen(line_split) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(first_number_buffer, line_split);

    line_split = strtok(NULL, " ");
    second_number_buffer = (char *) malloc(strlen(line_split) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(second_number_buffer, line_split);

    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", line,first_number_buffer,second_number_buffer);
}
```

input:

```
sum 23879238932898239832983298329839229383928329 239823983298392893289238932883290312803291832109230189
```

output:

```
sum
23879238932898239832983298329839229383928329
239823983298392893289238932883290312803291832109230189
```

The code can be improved in many ways. Some people pointed EOF is not properly checked within `read_line()`, and main can definitely be refactored in smaller functions.

However the idea of using `strtok()` as a substitute to `sscanf()` even with an indefinite number of tokens, for that case, works. See an example of a strtok inside a while: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: `scanf("%c", &current_letter); if(current_letter == UNIX_LINEBREAK || current_letter == EOF){` fails to detect end-of-file or input error.  Check return value of `scanf()` or even better: use `fgetc()`.

Comment: `extra_linebreak = (char)getchar();` assumes a `'\n'` must follow a `'\r'`.  As that is not a specification of a text file, best to `ungetc()` if assumption was false.

Comment: `int position = 0;` better as `size_t position = 0;` to cope with huge lines.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in the context of that application, that's the case! a `\r` will follow   a `\n`. We have `.in` files which sometimes are opened by windows users. When that happens windows changes the termination of lines, interchanging `\n` for `\r\n`. That part of the logic works for our inputs, I've tested it

Comment: However you're 100% right about the `EOF` issue, I have to fix it, thanks a lot

Comment: nluizsoliveira  My concern is a file with content like `"abc\r123\n"` or `"abc\r123\r\n"` being mis-read here. As I see it, there is a fair amount of cross usage of window's text files on *nix and visa-versa - and unfortunately files with both `"\n"` and `"\r\n"` line endings.  Robust code is prepared for these and does not assume a stand-alone `'\r'` is an end-of-line or a precursor to one.  IAC, not a beginner concern.